# How can I create a recurring appointment for First Wednesday of Every Month using Ical

Tags: outlook, icalendar, recurrence, rfc5545

How can I create a recurring appointment for First Wednesday of Every Month using Ical, Please see below ical file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH  
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150909T130000
DTSTAMP:20150909T053424Z
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=1
UID:77970@local
Location: Test
DESCRIPTION:Test
LAST-MODIFIED:20150909T053424Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: - test service
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Below Code is Working Fine for -- Occurs the first Sunday of every 1 month effective 04-10-2015 until 06-12-2015 from AM 11:00 to PM 12:00.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150910T110000
DTSTAMP:20150910T071744Z
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=1;UNTIL=20151210T120000
EXDATE:20151004T110000, 20151101T110000, 20151206T110000
UID:78106@local
Location:Test
DESCRIPTION:Test
LAST-MODIFIED:20150910T071744Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: test service
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

---

But this code for Every Monday is Not Working

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150910T080000
DTSTAMP:20150910T075935Z
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO;BYSETPOS=1;UNTIL=20151210T090000
UID:78121@local
Location:Test
DESCRIPTION:Test
LAST-MODIFIED:20150910T075935Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY: test service
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Looks good to me. What problem are you facing? You might want to try:

`RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1WE` which is a bit more common.

Comment: When I open the file it says " The ical file is not a valid Internet Calendar file"

Comment: Then outlook has a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Create an appointment in Outlook and save it as an ICS file. I got the following. Outlook has absolutely no problem opening that ICS file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20150910T120559Z
DESCRIPTION:\n
DTEND;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20151007T113000
DTSTAMP:20150910T120559Z
DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Standard Time":20151007T110000
LAST-MODIFIED:20150910T120559Z
PRIORITY:5
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=WE;BYSETPOS=1
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:First Wednesday of Every Month
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000F0DEF1869FEBD001000000000000000
    01000000050D17A24B21FB34F845623E567B81E99
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion rmj.rmm.rup.rpr">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted 
    from text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n<
    /BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

RFC5545 specifies that `DTSTART` is the first instance of your `RRULE` in your case you have

> DTSTART:20150909T130000

but Sept, 9th is a Wednesday not a Monday. Changing your `DTSTART` to:

> DTSTART:20150907T080000

allows the file to be opened by Outlook.

More details on `DTSTART` and `RRULE` :  [RFC5545 Event](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1)

> The "DTSTART" property for a "VEVENT" specifies the inclusive
> start of the event.  For recurring events, it also specifies the
> very first instance in the recurrence set.

So while in theory, it means that regardless of the rule, `DTSTART` should be appended to the list of occurences, what Outlook seems to do is to check for consistsance between `DTSTART` and the RRULE, hence your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR  
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN  
VERSION:2.0  
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN  
METHOD:PUBLISH  
  
BEGIN:VEVENT  
DTSTART:20150922T023000Z  
DTSTAMP:20150922T025844Z  
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU;BYSETPOS=4;WKST=SU;UNTIL=20151222T033000Z  
UID:1785  
Location:Test  
DESCRIPTION:test  
LAST-MODIFIED:20150922T025844Z  
SEQUENCE:0  
STATUS:CONFIRMED  
SUMMARY:test   
TRANSP:OPAQUE  
END:VEVENT  
END:VCALENDAR
```

Below link explains well..

https://www.techfolks.net/rrule-exdate-ical-recurring-event-appointment-example/